# Session Crashes in colab while doing preparing data for image colorization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

When I try to execute rgb to Lab operation on 5,000 images like this:

```
import cv2
X =[]
Y =[]
for img in img_arr:
    X.append(img[:,:,0]) 
    Y.append(img[:,:,1:] / 128) #A and B values range from -127 to 128, 
    #so we divide the values by 128 to restrict values to between -1 and 1.
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
X = X.reshape(X.shape+(1,)) #dimensions to be the same for X and Y
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)
```

My colab crashes.
I am trying to make a neural network which takes an input as l-channel of image and a*b as output to compare the error but i am not able to get the array for 5,000 images. Is there an alternative.

Comment: Most probably it will be crashing because of complete utilization of RAM. Have you checked resources while running the above piece of code in colab?

Comment: yeah colab is crashing because of complete utilisation of RAM but i don't know how to change my code